# How can I make Route without id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Don't working route "Admin" without {id}

```
public class PublicAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        { return "Public"; }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
    }
}

public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        { return "Admin"; }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin",
            "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
    }
}
```

I can use this one:
../admin/car/edit/3
But I can't this one:
../admin/car/edit

If I delete route "Default" I will abble to use both.
Why i can't use "../admin/car/edit" with "default" route?

Comment: you should define the admin route before default route

Answer (score 0):

I had to change order of area registration, like this:

```
        App_Start.AutoMapperConfig.Initialize();
        //AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        var adminArea = new rentcar2.Areas.Admin.AdminAreaRegistration();
        var adminAreaContext = new AreaRegistrationContext(adminArea.AreaName, RouteTable.Routes);
        adminArea.RegisterArea(adminAreaContext);

        var defaultArea = new rentcar2.Areas.Public.PublicAreaRegistration();
        var defaultAreaContext = new AreaRegistrationContext(defaultArea.AreaName, RouteTable.Routes);
        defaultArea.RegisterArea(defaultAreaContext);
```